# Ionic : Disable transition effect for particular states

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

In my ionic application when state changed views changed with "Slide-left" and "Slide-right" effect. But I want to disable this effect for 3 selected states.

I used `$ionicConfigProvider.views.transition = 'none'` in `config` block but it disabled this effect from all states.

How can I disable this effect from selected states only ?

Comment: Please try this: //here transition name
$ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection('forward');
//here next state name
$state.go("main.map");

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's helped me lot.

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options:

1) Using nav-transition directive.

```
<a nav-transition="none" href="#/home">Home</a>
```

2) Using $ionicHistory with the nextViewOptions method.

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
   disableAnimate: true
});
```